# Calling a function within conj in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm a newbie to Clojure and am a bit confused about how functions are called.

Let's say I have this function

```
(defn  foo [& fns] 
   #(apply (first fns) %&))
```

When I call `((foo + max min) 2 3 5 1 6 4)` it will return `21`.

When I define the function like this,

```
(defn  foo [& fns] 
   (conj [] #(apply (first fns) %&)))
```

I was expecting `((foo + max min) 2 3 5 1 6 4)` to return `[21]` but instead I get

```
Execution error (ArityException) at user/eval2258 (REPL:1).
Wrong number of args (6) passed to: clojure.lang.PersistentVector
```

Why is that? And how would I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> (defn  foo [& fns] 
>    (conj [] #(apply (first fns) %&)))
> ```
>
> I was expecting `((foo + max min) 2 3 5 1 6 4)` to return `[21]`...

Your original `foo` returns a function.  Now
you return a vector with a function in it.  Now when calling it, you are
calling the vector, thus the error message.

```
user=> ([] 1 2 3)
Execution error (ArityException) at user/eval150 (REPL:1).
Wrong number of args (3) passed to: clojure.lang.PersistentVector
```

To correct this, you would have put the result of the apply into the
vector, but still return a function.  But since you are not yet using
all passed in `fns` it's not clear, what to suggest from here.

This would give you the result, you are looking for:

```
(defn  foo [& fns] 
   #(vector (apply (first fns) %&)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though it answers my question, you are right I should be more clear with what I am trying to do. I asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030190/reimplementing-juxt-in-clojure